# How to get Django Book on Kindle?

Tags: python, django, kindle

The Django Book is freely available online.  A couple questions:

1. Is it possible to get it for free on the Kindle?
2. If so, how?

Comment: Readability is a chrome plugin that can turn any webpage into a readable "book", which can then be sent directly to a Kindle device. In retrospect, this would be a good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert other formats to Kindle:
http://calibre-ebook.com/

Comment: The last version of the docs fail converting to kindle with calibre. Here is the error: ValueError: Index has too many entries, calibre does not support generating multiple index records at this time.

Comment: Here you can download: https://github.com/pferretti/docsforkindle

Answer (score 1):

I'd first search Amazon's store.

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-text&field-keywords=the+django+book&x=0&y=0

(This yields no free books entitled "The Django Book.")

The next step may be to see if you can get permission to convert this book over to the Kindle's format.  A link to some instructions are here:  http://blog.the-ebook-reader.com/2010/07/11/kindle-format-conversion-guide/

I've not converted anything over so I can't be much help, but maybe this will get you started.